# the tooltip does not reflect what I want. Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I spent all day trying to make this work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM1jx.png)

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Can you please share a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Please read [our guide on the `DateAxis`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/date-axis/):

> Data granularity affects how axis grid is drawn, and how labels are formatted.

What is happening is that the chart is trying to figure out a frequency of dates for your data. With the 4 plots of data in your screenshot, the `DateAxis`' `baseInterval.timeUnit` will be adjusted to a weekly granularity.

You can try manually adjusting the granularity to say, daily, e.g.:

```js
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  timeUnit: "day",
  count: 1
};
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of demo, shows the date in the axis tooltips are now accurate]

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/8b9bb394a7628bf6092786344f6e7513